# Resharper offers to remove redundant inheritance from Window class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, window, resharper

In WPF projects Resharper offers to remove inheritance from `Window` class as redundant:

```
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It is become possible to remove even `using System.Windows;`.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Why actually he offer this and why without that inheritance everything works fine? As I read in books of WPF any window anyway should be inherited...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XAML code-behind files are partial classes. The code generated by the compiler from the XAML file also includes the Window derivation so the one in the code-behind is redundant.

Comment: It gets rid of the Resharper warning but also can make the code less readable for newbies. It doesn't make a difference in the final output either way so it's really personal preference.

Comment: Youre not actually removing the window inheritance. The class still inherits Window, just not in your code behind file. If you remove it in the code-behind, is still specified in the designer file. If you have it in your code-behind, then it is then specified in two places. That is why it is marked as redundant.

Comment: See also [C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods): "*All the parts that specify a base class must agree, but parts that omit a base class still inherit the base type. Parts can specify different base interfaces, and the final type implements all the interfaces listed by all the partial declarations.*"

Answer (score 3):

Your `MainWindow` class (like most designer-generated classes) is a `partial` class. This means that the implementation for your class can be broken up into multiple files, as long as they're all within the same assembly.

Because the designer-generated file for `MainWindow` also contains `: Window`, it's not necessary to include it in any other files.